# Visual Studio 2010: When creating new project vs2010 wants to open html file of wizard

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

As title says when I'm creating new project in vs2010 it wants to open wizard html in browser. The file it wants to open:

> file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0/VC/VCWizards/AppWiz/Generic/Application/html/1033/default.htm

So in the end I can't create project. Any ideas what can be wrong? I'm using Windows 7 64bit. I tried uninstalling Internet Explorer but it didn't solve my problem.

I'll explain how it works now:

1. I click File -> New -> Project...
2. I choose win32 console app, set name, click ok.
3. Now after ok it should show wizard but instead of it it wants to open html in firefox. The file it wants to open is mentioned above. It looks like it can't somehow show this html in application because this html have wizzards buttons and text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstalling old Internet Explorer 8 and installing Internet Explorer 9 solved this problem.

Comment: Accept this as the answer when sufficient time has passed.