# VS 2010 C++ Express, project creation error

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2010, styles, project

I open vs go into create new project, win32 console application, and then it shows me this.

[image: Visual C++ window showing HTML]

It looks like the XML styling for the project creation form.

Comment: That's a dialect of HTML.  Haven't seen the `<SYMBOL>` tag before, but it's probably some extension VS uses to do something akin to HTAs.

Comment: Maybe a re-install will fix something...

Comment: Something is wrong with Application Wizard files (or with VC++ way of handling them). These are two HTML files located in ...\AppWiz\...\html\1033 directory of VC++.

Comment: I have reinstalled and repaired I am going to reinstall all my visual studio tools and most microsoft dependancies, repair registry and clean temp files and then reinstall if that doesn't work I don't know what I will do because I don't want to have to backup all of my stuff and do a clean install just for VS

Comment: Just got VS 11 Beta and it did the same thing :(

Comment: You're not one of those weirdos that totally remove IE from their computers, are you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010: When creating new project vs2010 wants to open html file of wizzard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766942/visual-studio-2010-when-creating-new-project-vs2010-wants-to-open-html-file-of)