# VS 2010 - Opening Win32 Application Wizard as .html file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I'm a little bit reluctant as to ask question, as it was asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766942/visual-studio-2010-when-creating-new-project-vs2010-wants-to-open-html-file-of), but the problem is, it wasn't answered sufficiently enough, so I'm forced to ask it second time.

So, just as previously mentioned asker I'm trying to create new project in Microsoft Visual 2010. And instead of showing normal window, it [prompts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRA1V.png) me to save .html file, as shown in picture below.

[image]

Saving it and that opening it results [in the following window:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TWhq.png)

[image]

though it does nothing - just page with no influence over the project at all.

Notably, this happens not only for Win32 application, but for MFC applications too.
As for the cause of this I don't know of it. As you can see from first screenshot, I was doing Web applications before hand, but I didn't change any of preferences at all (though, my guess is that it's somehow connected).

As for solving this issue, I tried uninstalling IE8, as stated in previous topic, but that didn't help. Also, I tried doing Tools -> Import & Export Settings -> Reset, but it didn't help either.

Please, if someone know solution for this, tell me - I'm out of my wits with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, many parts of this case related to  disturbing or collisions among files. In my experience, some programmes, which were installed recently, might cause this concern.

I'd like to recommend to install all service packs and update patches for VS 2010 and then try it again. If it doesn't fixed, reinstalling VS will be a relevant solution for saving your time and conserving your passion.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is occurred because some Visual studio setting is corrupted.

I'd like to recommend to reset settings like following
    start > Run> devenv.exe /resetsettings